# Is <task:annotation-driven/> needed if @Scheduled is present within <context:component-scan> range?

Tags: java, spring

The configuration element `<task:annotation-driven/>` (or `@EnableScheduling` annotation) is supposed to turn on asynchronous tasks in Spring. However, I noticed that having one or more `@Scheduled` annotation within `<context:component-scan/>` range seems to be the necessary condition for async tasks to be started.

Resorting to cleaning the code of `<task:annotation-driven/>` and `@EnableScheduling` does not prevent asynchronous tasks from starting. Why?

Comment: Only adding `<task:annotation-driven /`> or `@EnableScheduling` isn't going to do much. You only instruct the context that you want to use annotations to drive async calls. To trigger those calls you need either `@Async` for async calls or `@Scheduled` for periodic calls. Without the `<task:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableScheduling` the annotations trigger nothing.

Comment: You'd have to show us your contexts. What you are describing is not possible.

Comment: Can't show the context, it's too long and messy, nobody would care to look. But I'm positive there are neither `annotation-driven` nor '@EnableScheduling` anywhere in the code, I've made a thorough search.

Comment: Then there is something else. We cannot help without seeing it. Maybe you are manually declaring beans that `@EnableScheduling` usually declares.

Comment: i have the same problems, i commented <task:annotation-driven /> and without @ EnableScheduling in my code, but the @Scheduled always run.